# ¿Cómo hacer que los botones funcionen bien?

Tags: java, android

¿Porqué mi botón tarda tanto en arrancar la URL del *streaming* y tarda tanto en cambiar las imágenes entre `play` y `pause`?.

A este `player` se le puede añadir también un botón "música", al dar clic en el botón que cambie el link del *streaming* con una carpeta remota de un servidor que contiene canciones.

Si alquien me puede dar el código ya que soy novato en Android y programación.

```
static MediaPlayer mPlayer;
ImageButton bt_start_pause;
boolean paused = true;
String url = "link radio";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 bt_start_pause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bt_start_pause);
 bt_start_pause.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
 bt_start_pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

  public void onClick(View v) {
   if (paused) {
    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    try {
     mPlayer.setDataSource(url);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
     mPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    mPlayer.start();
    paused = false;
    bt_start_pause.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
    //when MediaPlayer stared, pause button is shown
   } else {
    if (mPlayer != null && mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
     mPlayer.stop();
     paused = true;
     bt_start_pause.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
     //when MediaPlayer paused, startbutton is shown
    }
   }
  }
 });
}

protected void onDestroy() {
 super.onDestroy();
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 if (mPlayer != null) {
  mPlayer.release();
  mPlayer = null;
 }
}
}
```

Comment: Cuando tienes componentes que son pesados, por ejemplo un MediaPlayer o un reproductor de video, streaming, etc, trata de inicial izar los componentes solo una vez. En el ejemplo que muestras estas inicializando tu mediaPlayer cada vez que haces click. Puedes inicializarlo solo una vez fuera de tu método `onClick()` y luego solo jugar con los métodos `pausa()`, `isPlaying()`, `pause()` para tus requerimientos.